# Assembly references in T4 in Visual Studio 2012 .NET 4.5

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, t4, .net-4.5

I am having problems using the T4 tool in Visual Studio 2012. My .tt-files have an assembly directive to a 64-bit .DLL built in the same solution. This is the output from debugging the tt file:

> Error 308 The host threw an exception while trying to resolve the
>   assembly reference '$(TargetDir)\DCSGenerator.dll'. The transformation
>   will not be run. The following Exception was thrown:
>   System.IO.FileLoadException: The given assembly name or codebase was
>   invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047)    at
>   System.Reflection.AssemblyName.nInit(RuntimeAssembly& assembly,
>   Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean raiseResolveEvent)    at
>   System.Reflection.AssemblyName..ctor(String assemblyName)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.GlobalAssemblyCacheHelper.GetLocation(String
>   strongName)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.VSHost.TextTemplatingService.ResolveAssemblyReference(String
>   assemblyReference)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.Engine.ResolveAssemblyReferences(ITextTemplatingEngineHost
>   host, TemplateProcessingSession
>   session)  C:\TFS\Dev01\CorePlatform\CoreServices\ImportExport.NET\ImportExport.NET\DicomInterface\TemplateUtilFunctions.tt    0   0   ImportExport.NET
>   (CoreServices\ImportExport.NET\ImportExport.NET)

Is anyone else having problems with this?

Best Regards,

UPDATE 2012-11-14 09:17 (CET): Visual Studio and hence the T4 generator runs as a 32-bit application and my assemblies are built as 64bit DLLs. This might be a source of the problem.

UPDATE 2012-11-14 09:43 (CET): Tried to reference the assembly using the full path but this didn't solve the problem.

Comment: VS runs as a 32bit so if the dll referenced is not marked 'Any CPU' but requires 64bit arch then T4 library hosted by VS can't load the dll (a 32bit process can't load 64bit dlls and vice versa)

Comment: I suspected this after searching for similar probems on the Internet. Never managed to switch the target platform to 32/64-bit, because of some solution constraints I guess. I will follow this lead however. Thanks!

Comment: The '$(TargetDir)\DCSGenerator.dll' in the exception looks odd to me as the exception usually shows the derived path, not the source. Try a hard code full path, just to see.

Comment: Thanks Rob. I tried it but it resulted with the same error.

Answer (score 0):

As I suspected, the problem was solved by building the dependency assemblies with `PlatformTarget AnyCPU`. Now the generated DLLs are both 32- and 64-bit assembly compatible.